# URL rewrite works with 301 or absolute path but not without

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal

I'm trying to show the user the content of `http://www.mysite.com/booking-request?code=###` when visiting a url such as `http://www.mysite.com/booking/ZHTU78`

I'm sure this is simple, but I cannot understand why the following rule is not working for me. All I get is a 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^booking\/([\w\d]+)$ /booking-request?code=$1 [L]
```

If I change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^booking\/([\w\d]+)$ /booking-request?code=$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works, but with the obvious undesirable side effect of actually redirecting the browser to `http://www.mysite.com/booking-request?code=###`

I've also tried changing the url to redirect to to a single `/` to make sure it should be looking for an existing page, but no change.

It *might* be pertinent to mention this is on a drupal site and `/booking-request` is essentially a basic page, so drupal will have some functionality to redirect this page anyway, however I wouldn't have thought it should matter in this case.

**edit**
Here's a link to the whole htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/KPE6DK6N

Comment: Checking this at [madewithlove](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), I got it working by removing the escape on the slash: `^booking/`.

Comment: Share all other htaccess rules as well. One of them is probably interfering here.

Comment: @icabod unfortunately that didn't work. I've also added a pastebin of all the htaccess rules. It's pretty much a standard drupal htaccess with a couple of additions.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^booking/([\w\d]+)$ /booking-request?code=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^booking/([\w\d]+)$ http://www.mysite.com/booking-request?code=$1 [L]
```

It should work.

Comment: The first suggestion still shows a 404, the second suggestion has the same effect as adding `R=301` at the end of the rule. It does redirect, however the url changes with it, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: http://www.mysite.com/booking-request?code=### - what is a page type? Views? Custom module? Can you find synonym path for this url?

Comment: That page is a basic page content type. I'm not sure what a synonym path is, or where I might look for it?

Comment: "basic page" - is node type? Why parameter 'code' is necessary for node? You can look synonym - /admin/config/search/path

Comment: sorry, the content type is called basic page, in the database it is just saved as *page*. The synonym is *booking-request* which is linked to *node/4527*. I'm using the url parameter as the value of it will be dynamic.

Comment: Try it: RewriteRule ^booking/([\w\d]+)$ index.php?q=node/4527&code=$1 [L]

Comment: That does redirect, however again it changes the url. I quickly tried turning of *clean urls* incase this was interfering, but it still changed the url.